# python/bottle and returning a dict

Tags: python, gson, bottle

I am using python/bottle to return a dict/json to my android app ( the app using GSON to parse into JSON).  It doesn't seem to parse the python text correctly.

Here is what python returns:

```
[{u'slot': -1.0, u'rnd': -1.0}]
```

But Gson sets slot = 0 and round =0, so it is either not reading it properly or just setting it to default values.  How can I get python to not return the unicode encoded string and just a regular or string.  Here is the offending python code

```
...
return str(move)
```

Move is the object the is returned for a pymongo find query and at the time of test it was [{u'slot': -1.0, u'rnd': -1.0}], well python added the 'u', when we look at the values in rockmongo it doesn't have the 'u'.

Comment: This does not seem like a complete, correct example.

Comment: This may be a stupid quesiton, but are you aware that you should return json.dumps(move) to make it json?

Comment: If I know that do you think I would ask the question.  To Marcin, I guess I should have said that when I trace on the Android side the string that str(move) return is [{u'slot': -1.0, u'rnd': -1.0}]

Comment: using json.dumps did work..., post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

If you want bottle to turn your dict into JSON, then return the dict. Not str(...), not a list with a dict in it, but just the dict.

Example:

```
from bottle import route

@route('/some/path')
def some_callback():
    return {'slot': -1.0, 'rnd': -1.0}
```